# Part of Jquery "hide/show" working, other part isn't

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am able to get only part of my jquery working. It's driving me crazy because the `desgn_bx_hidden` and `des_txt` are both hiding and showing but the inside content of `desgn_bx_hidden` isn't showing and I want to be able to style it with CSS. Actually it is showing in the browser but I can't get the css to effect it and in firebug it shows that the `desgn_bx` toggles to show but the inside content doesn't. I've tried changing the content inside with the changes. It has two links inside and originally had 2 more divs wrapping around it to format the font but I took that out trying to simplify.... anyone run into this before?

```
$(".desgn_bx").mouseover(function () {
    $(".desgn_bx_hidden").show();
    $(".des_txt").hide();

});
$(".desgn_bx").mouseout(function () {
    $(".desgn_bx_hidden").hide();
    $(".des_txt").show();
});


<div class="desgn_bx">
    <a href="/design"></a>
    <div class="desgn_bx_hidden block-quicktabs" style="display: none;">
        <a id="quicktabs-tab-2-0" class="qt_tab active" 
        href="/design?quicktabs_2=0#quicktabs- 2">Residential</a>
        <a id="quicktabs-tab-2-1" class="qt_tab active" 
        href="/design?quicktabs_2=1#quicktabs-2">Commercial</a>
    </div>
    <p class="des_txt" style="display: block;">
    <span>Interior Design </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is the link: http://freespiriteurodesign.com.b1.bloomsite.net/

Thank you!!

Comment: You really need to structure the code so it's readable.

Comment: I'm looking at your demo and have no idea what effect I'm supposed to be seeing or where I'm supposed to hover.  It appears to work here, although not formatted very well.

Comment: @Sondre I've seen considerably worse formatting from people who have more experience on the site, and at least they **did** include code. Either way, I've fixed the formatting now - should be able to read it easily.

Comment: wow didn't realize there would be so much negativity when I'm trying to reach out for a little help:( I'm trying to format on this site and perhaps the indenting isn't perfect but it does looks readable, plus I included the actual site.I'm just looking for a solution or a pointer in the right direction:(

Comment: the sites created in drupal 6, I don't think that matters but just a little background in case anyone has any ideas.... referring to the original question...thank you in advanced:)

Comment: @ristenk1 Sorry if my comment seemed negative. Just wanted to point out that the code needed some formatting. Well formatted code will make it easier for others to help you. If people feel that the code is poorly formatted it's less likely that's you'll get any good answers to the question. Nothing negative intended

Comment: That's ok Sondre:) I was just confused as to why the question was given a negative one(-1) when it was a legitamate question. Everything worked out fine and thank you so much for all of the comments, a developer community really helps me grow professionally. I was under a tight deadline and trying to work through the weekend to land a potential job while juggling my three children so sloppy code was def. my fault but the best that I could do at the moment. No worries though...I might have even gotten the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
$(".desgn_bx").mouseover(function () {
                        $(".desgn_bx_hidden").show();
                        $(".desgn_bx_hidden").children().show();
                        $(".des_txt").hide();

                    });
  $(".desgn_bx").mouseout(function () {
                        $(".desgn_bx_hidden").hide();
                        $(".desgn_bx_hidden").children().hide();
                        $(".des_txt").show();
                    });
```

It wasn't working because it didn't have the children

Answer (score 0):

If your not hitting the target element with css, something else is probably wrong, but try a little basic structuring and maybe you'll figure it out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".desgn_bx").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(".desgn_bx_hidden").show();
            $(".des_txt").hide();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(".desgn_bx_hidden").hide();
            $(".des_txt").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't really think it's the jquery... the hiding and showing is working for desgn_bx <div> and <p> des_txt... just not on any of the elements I put within the desgn_bx div...

Comment: maybe selecting farther into the div with the jquery is necessary: $(".desgn_bx_hidden, .desgn_bx_hidden block-quicktabs").show();

Comment: Your probably not hitting your target, try getting some values or content from the elements into the console to see if the selector is correct.

Comment: Got it!
It wasn't working because it didn't have the children part of the function:) I'll post it in answers when I can, right now stackoverflow is making me wait 3 hours b/c I don't have enough points